# Why is the skin burned in chatas but not olah?

Tags: korban, parashat-vayikra

I read in the artscroll Chumash that the skin of the korban was given to the Kohen in an olah after everything else had gone on the mizbeach, but that for a chatat the skin was burnt outside of the camp with the rest of the animal that wasnt brought on the mizbeach. Does anyone have a good explanation for the difference in procedure?

Comment: Some Chataot are eaten and some are burnt, called Chataot haNe'ekhalot and Chataot haNisrafot respectively. Have you read Zevakhim Chapter 5 recently? It has a good breakdown of the various kinds of Korbanot.

Comment: It depends where the blood was put. Also called penimiyos and chitsoniyos.

Comment: My main question was about the skin (burning vs giving to the kohen)

Comment: @gabriel the problem is though that the skin isn't that different from the rest of it. All Kodshei Kalim have the skin go to the owner. All Kodshei Kodshim it goes to the Kohanim except Chataot hanisrafot where the whole animal including its hide is burned outside the Mikdash.

Comment: Ok so then why is the skin burnt by chataot hanisrafot?